# How to log an error when a JDBC request returns no data from DB in Jmeter?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

I need to know how to log an error when a JDBC request returns no data from DB in Jmeter.

I have got:

**JDBC request**

Query:

```
SELECT names 
FROM   customers
```

Variable names:
namesCustomers

**Then I have got a BeanShell postProcessor with script:**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
JMeterUtils.setProperty("namesCustomer", vars.get("namesCustomer_1"));
```

And finally a simple controller called "set variables" which calls an external file with the following code:
vars.put("namesCustomer",JMeterUtils.getProperty("namesCustomer"));

The problem is that in another SOAP request I am using the variable namesCustomer_1, and if no data is returned from DB this request fails. I need to log an error when the JDBC returns no data.

If I add to the post processor:

log.error("Error example");

I see the error logged in jmeter.log when this request is ran. I need something like:

```
if(JMeterUtils.setProperty("namesCustomer", vars.get("namesCustomer_1")).toString().length()==0){
log.error("DB returned no results")
}
```

Any Ideas on how to log an error when the JDBC request returns no data?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done a little bit easier. If JMeter Variable is not set, it'll be `null`, not empty string.

So I would suggest amending your code as follows:

```
String namesCustomer = vars.get("namesCustomer_1");

if (namesCustomer == null) {
    log.error("namesCustomer_1 variable is not set");
} else {
    props.put("namesCustomer", namesCustomer);
}
```

`props` is a shorthand to access current set of JMeter Properties, there is no need to use `JMeterUtils.setProperty()` method.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.